# Boto3 DynamoDB put item if value does not equal string

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm using the python Boto3 SDK for interfacing with DynamoDB. I'd like to add / update an item into DynamoDB only if one of the keys value does not equal "open". Ex. If the value for eventStatus does not equal "open", then allow item to be updated, else, don't update the item at all.

I've included a code sample below of what I think it should be but it doesn't appear that the conditional is being evaluated properly. The code below should put the item into the table but it is not.

```
import boto3
import botocore.exceptions


dynamnodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

try:
    put_response = dynamnodb_client.put_item(
                TableName='TABLENAME',
                Item={
                    'event_arn': {'S': 'arn:aws:health:us-east-1::event/EC2/AWS_EC2_OPERATIONAL_ISSUE/AWS_EC2_OPERATIONAL_ISSUE_VKTXI_EXAMPLE124'},
                    'service': {'S': 'EC2'},
                    'startTime': {'S': '1587462325.096'},
                    'endTime': {'S': '1587464204.774'},
                    'lastUpdateTime': {'S': '1587464204.865'},
                    'failureNotificationStatus': {'S': 'sent'},
                    'failureNotificationTimestamp': {'S': '1587462325.096'},
                    'resolutionNotificationStatus': {'S': 'sent'},
                    'resolutionNotificationTimestamp': {'S': '1587464204.774'},
                    'associatedSnsTopic': {'S': ''},
                    'failureEventString': {'S': '"arn":"arn:aws:health:us-east-1::event/CLOUDWATCH/AWS_CLOUDWATCH_OPERATIONAL_ISSUE/AWS_CLOUDWATCH_OPERATIONAL_ISSUE_event-1606317831882","service":"CLOUDWATCH","eventTypeCode":"AWS_CLOUDWATCH_OPERATIONAL_ISSUE","eventTypeCategory":"issue","region":"us-east-1","startTime":1606316400.0,"endTime":1606373818.0,"lastUpdatedTime":1606373894.864,"statusCode":"closed","eventScopeCode":"PUBLIC"}'},
                    'eventStatus': {'S': 'closed'},
                    'eventScope': {'S': 'PUBLIC'},
                    },
                ReturnValues='ALL_OLD',
                ReturnConsumedCapacity='INDEXES',
                ConditionExpression='eventStatus <> :v_eventStatus', 
                ExpressionAttributeValues={':v_eventStatus': {'S': 'open'}},
    )
    print(put_response)
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] != 'ConditionalCheckFailedException':
        pass
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've found the DynamoDB documentation to be extremely lacking around both ConditionExpression and ExpressionAttributeValues. I'm not entirely sure if ExpressionAttributeValues is even needed for this. I would have though I could have just done the following expression `eventStatus <> 'open'`

Comment: The code looks good to me. Could you try getting rid of the extra brackets? In other words, use `ConditionExpression='eventStatus <> :v_eventStatus'`.

Comment: Shoot, that came over in the copy and pasting of code. Unfortunately that didn't fix it either. When I set the status to `':v_eventStatus': {'S': 'closed'}}` it still adds the value even though it shouldn't.

Comment: Conditional expression issues aside for one moment, note that `put_item` replaces any existing item; it doesn't update it (for which you can use `update_item`). Also, perhaps for later, you should consider using the resource-level [Table](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#table) so that boto3 will do native Python type marshalling, so you can write `'eventStatus': 'closed'` instead of `'eventStatus': {'S': 'closed'}`.

Comment: @jarmod - That make sense about the updating of an item. Even so, I want to not write the item to the table if the value of an item equals "closed". I should be able to do so if the table is empty and the condition is met.

Comment: So, what is actually going wrong? Are you saying that this code will not put a new item? Or that it will not update an existing item (that has the same key) that has a status that is not 'open'? Or do both fail for you? What errors happen in each case?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue and the following might work for you too:

add imports of `boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key & Attr`

and use `ConditionExpression` with something like `ConditionExpression=Attr("attributeName").ne(123)` or
`ConditionExpression=Key("attributeName").contains('abc')`

`contains()`: Check if a String attribute contains a particular substring or a Set attribute contains a particular element

also you can specify `ExpressionAttributeValues` as:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues={
      ':v_eventStatus': 'open'
}
```

Other conditions available here https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/dynamodb.html#ref-dynamodb-conditions